# How can I control UVs with a rig?

Tags: uv, rigging

So, I am working on a robot that looks like [eve from wal-e](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=eve%20from%20walle&oq=eve%20from%20wae&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5215j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). So, now I want to control the eyes like a rig but still want them to look like it is coming out from a screen (which is basically black now cause the screen is turned off ). The eyes are nothing more than just two blue dots. So if only there was a way I could manipulate the UVs to face a object or deform like a object maybe? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4OxkWCM5yM3Q0wwSGdOdUZYMVU/view) is a 360. So my question is how do I animate the eyes while still having them look like an image mapped on the eyes?

[image: a still]

Comment: That's what exactly UV Warp is for: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_warp.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BopkonvbCEE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be helpful. UV Project where an empty can move and control the UV texture. You can either animate the empty directly, or parent it to another bone, or object, or...

[image]

p.s. if you press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> with the empty selected you can rotate the texture like an orbit.

**Update:** In response to extra blink question.

Above the initial shape I added a duplicate which floats just above the surface and repeated the process of adding a UV project - the difference is the second UV had a strip of alpha transparency.

[image]

My guess is more layers can be added for extra effect. Here I added some movement to the new UV alpha layer...

[image]

...and then added some scaling to origin UV eye texture.

[image]

Comment: although this has already helped a lot and thx for that but any idea how would i control things like a blink ?

Comment: thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, how you want to move the eyes.
But from how i understand you dont like to use bones for it to move ?.
Well another option is to do it using shapekeys.

A shapekey can be assigned a value from -1 to 1 where 0 is no effect.
they can even be combinations, and they are often used for facial expressions.
here some more info :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zijo8ly6pyI